# Get Groups info for contact using Google's gdata

Tags: c#, contacts, gdata

I'm using the google gdata driver to get an account's contacts. One of the things I'd like to be able to get the group membership info for each contact. I've seen the `Contact.GroupMembership` collection, but as far as I can tell the only things it contains is an `HRef` property, which is just a URL. Is there something I'm missing that would have a name, uri, etc for a contact's Group?

Answer (score 0):

For a list of all Group Names and References
(Href is the Atom Id, cr is as an instance of your ContactRequest)

```
Feed<Group> fg = cr.GetGroups();
foreach (Group group in fg.Entries)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Atom Id: " + group.Id);
     Console.WriteLine("Group Name: " + group.Title);
}
```